# Алгоритм определения наготы в пользовательском контенте андроид - приложения

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер, подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно организовать в своем андроид -приложении( в котором пользователи могут загружать свои изображения) отсеивание контента, содержащего порнографические сцены. Фейсбук, инстаграм и тд отсеивают подобные изображения. поэтому у меня два вопроса :

1. собственно, интересует алгоритм
2. готовые рабочие решения (библиотеки) которые можно просто использовать.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите на [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). Они одним из назначений сервиса заявляют фильтрацию нежелательного контента.

А вообще ничего надежней людей пока не придумали. У пользователей должна быть кнопка "пожаловаться" с моментальной отменой публикации и передачей модератору.